# Prove that the function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

Question: Let $S$ be the sawtooth function defined by

$$
S(u) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            u & \quad 0 \leq u \leq 1 \\
            u - 1 & \quad 1 < u \leq 2
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Prove that $S$ is Riemann integrable.

**My Attempt**

If $S : [0, 2]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we want to show that $S$ is Riemann integrable.

We first need to show that $S_1 : [0, 1] \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $S(u) = u$ is Riemann integrable. Suppose we let $P_n$ be a partition of the interval $[0, 1]$. Then we will have

$$P_n = \left\{[0, \frac{1}{n}],[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}],...,[\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]\right\}$$

Then it follows that
\begin{align*}
u_i - u_{i - 1} &= \frac{1}{n} \\
m_i &= \frac{i - 1}{n} \\
M_i &= \frac{i}{n}
\end{align*}

Then from here, we can say that for a given $\epsilon > 0$
\begin{align*}
U(S_1, P) - L(S_1, P) &= \sum_{i = 1}^n M_i(u_i - u_{i - 1}) - \sum_{i = 1}^n m_i(u_i - u_{i - 1}) < \epsilon \\
\end{align*}

I am not exactly sure if I am on the right track, and I am not exactly sure how I should proceed from here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy way to do this.

Just observe that for any $x,y\in [0,2]$ for any $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta >0$ such that
$$
|S(x) - S(y)| < \epsilon/2
$$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta $

Consider the partition $P_n$ as you considered in question such that $1/n <\delta$. Since $S$ is continous in each interval it attains maximum and minimum there, so $M_i = S(a_i)$ and $m_i = S(b_i)$. Now just observe that $|a_i - b_i| < \frac{1}{n} < \delta$ which implies that $M_i - m_i < \epsilon /2$.

So $U(S,P_n) - L(S,P_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (M_i - m_i)(u_i - u_{i-1}) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} (u_n - u_0) = \epsilon$

Comment: So does that mean that $u_n - u_0 = 2$ such that $2 \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$? I think that is where you are trying to get at, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: Consider the partition $P_n = \{[u_0,u_1],...,[u_{n-1},u_{n}]\} $ where $u_i$ is strictly increasing sequence and with $u_0 =0$ and $u_n=2$

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes it easier for me to understand

Comment: Actually this procedure can be imitated for any continous function in compact interval (such functions will be uniformly continous) to show that it is Riemann integrable .

Comment: So is there like a bit more "complicated" version to this kind of proof?